# Why does Runspace.OpenAsync() ignore InitialSessionState?

Tags: c#, powershell, async-await

I am writing code to interface with PowerShell. I originally had the following:

```
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState))
{
    runspace.Open();
```

This code works just fine. However, since this code is actually already in an async method, I wrote the following just to experiment:

```
public static Task OpenTaskAsync(this Runspace runspace)
{
    if (runspace.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.Opened)
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    EventHandler<RunspaceStateEventArgs> stateHandler = null;
    stateHandler = (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.RunspaceStateInfo.Reason != null)
        {
            runspace.StateChanged -= stateHandler;
            tcs.TrySetException(e.RunspaceStateInfo.Reason);
        }
        else if (e.RunspaceStateInfo.State == RunspaceState.Opened)
        {
            runspace.StateChanged -= stateHandler;
            tcs.TrySetResult(null);
        }
    };
    runspace.StateChanged += stateHandler;
    runspace.OpenAsync();

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

However, after changing my code to this:

```
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState))
{
    await runspace.OpenTaskAsync();
```

my tests now fail. The reason for this is PowerShell can no longer find the commands from a module that is imported into my InitialSessionState (prior to runspace creation). I cannot determine why this is. I have debugged and the runspace is open and available after this task completes, and I do not proceed to invoke any commands until it does. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the runspace open code in reflector and see one thing that might explain it. In `LocalRunspace.DoOpenHelper()` the `StateChanged` event (when state changes to "Opened") occurs *before* modules are imported. It looks like you could poll on the default drive being set (in `InitialSessionState.SetSessionStateDrive()`) as a workaround.

Comment: Interesting, I had also looked at the decompiled code (through ReSharper/dotPeek). I must have missed that detail. I checked again, and you are correct. That is unfortunate, since there doesn't seem to be a clean alternate solution (ie. polling as you mentioned). Oh well. I wonder why they would provide asynchronous methods without any way to wait on them (even an IAsyncResult).

Comment: I can only speculate, but in some sense the runspace is "opened" at that point. It's "ready for business". Unfortunately not ready for business that requires imported modules. You could change the initial session state to execute some powershell code (maybe a tiny module) to signal it has been loaded somehow. (now you can play "pick the least offensive hack")